# Find secuentially occurrences of all String[] in a given String

Tags: java, arrays, string, iterator

I have a pair of Strings in an array to check in another String:

```
String[] validPair = "{"[BOLD]", "[/BOLD]" };
String toCheck = "Example [BOLD]bold long text[/BOLD] other example [BOLD]bold short[/BOLD]";
```

I need to check the balance of the tags, I know how to check if a string is inside another string, also how to achieve this  using both `indexOf` of `validPair` content across the string and saving references, but is an ugly way and **I don't wanna reinvent the wheel**.

Something like :

```
int lastIndex = 0;
while (lastIndex != -1) {
    int index = toCheck.findNextOccurrence(validPair, lastIndex); // here use indexOf
    System.out.println(index);
    lastIndex = index;
}
```

I was guessing if **there is a way I can check `nextOccurrence` of any of the String's in `String[] validPair` in the `String toCheck`**?

A kind of `Iterator` or `Tokenizer` but not splitting the string and giving only occurrences of the contents of the `array` (or `List` or any other `Object`).

OR:

```
OwnIterator ownIterator = new OwnIterator<String>(toCheck, validPair);
while (toCheck.hasNext()) {
    String next = toCheck.findNextOccurrence();
    System.out.println(next);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[BOLD]
[/BOLD]
[BOLD]
[/BOLD]
```

Comment: what is the desired output of the entire thing? Just yes/no wether or not the tags are balanced or the indices tuples, or. ..? What exactly have you tried so far to get that output?

Comment: just next index of any of the occurrences in `validPair` i will update

Comment: @luk2302 please kindly check my update

Comment: You might want to look into regular expressions, building one to represent the set of open tag, contents and end tag. It will be much easier if the tags cannot be nested, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. it is using array of regular expressions to search for every item in `validPair` separetely then combine all found occurrences into one list (and its iterator)

```
public class OwnIterator implements Iterator 
{
    private Iterator<Integer> occurrencesItr;

    public OwnIterator(String toCheck, String[] validPair) {
        // build regex to search for every item in validPair
        Matcher[] matchValidPair = new Matcher[validPair.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < validPair.length ; i++) {
            String regex = 
                    "(" +    // start capturing group
                    "\\Q" +  // quote entire input string so it is not interpreted as regex
                    validPair[i] +  // this is what we are looking for, duhh 
                    "\\E" +  // end quote
                    ")" ;    // end capturing group
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            matchValidPair[i] = p.matcher(toCheck);
        }
        // do the search, saving found occurrences in list
        List<Integer> occurrences = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < matchValidPair.length ; i++) {
            while (matchValidPair[i].find()) {
                occurrences.add(matchValidPair[i].start(0)+1);  // +1 if you want index to start at 1 
            }
        }
        // sort the list 
        Collections.sort(occurrences);
        occurrencesItr = occurrences.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return occurrencesItr.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Object next()
    {
        return occurrencesItr.next();
    }
}
```

a quick test :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] validPair = {"[BOLD]", "[/BOLD]" };
    String toCheck = "Example [BOLD]bold long text[/BOLD] other example [BOLD]bold short[/BOLD]";
    OwnIterator itr = new OwnIterator(toCheck, validPair);
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
}
```

gives desired output:

```
9
29
51
67
```

EDIT:
found a better solution, with just one regular expression that includes all items in `validPair` with "or" condition (`|`). then you have the Matcher's own `find()` method as the iterator:

```
    String regex = "(";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < validPair.length ; i++) {
        regex += (i == 0 ? "" : "|") +  // add "or" after first item
                "\\Q" +  // quote entire input string so it is not interpreted as regex
                validPair[i] +  // this is what we are looking for, duhh 
                "\\E";  // end quote
    }
    regex += ")";
    System.out.println("using regex : " + regex);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(toCheck);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```

you get the output

```
using regex : (\Q[BOLD]\E|\Q[/BOLD]\E)
[BOLD]
[/BOLD]
[BOLD]
[/BOLD]
```

Comment: great @sharon, just, you didn't nottice the last modification.... there is a way to get the name of the tag instead the position??' sorry for last minute change.... :$

Comment: maybe you can achieve that on your own? you just need to replace the Matcher method (instead of `start(group-number)` to something else). really a small change and you will gain some (needed) experience in Java regex

Comment: found a better solution that uses one reg expression. see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
int first = toCheck.indexOf(validPair[0]);
boolean ok = first > -1 && toCheck.indexOf(validPair[1], first) > 0;
```